# Manually generated <a href='/link'> code in Ember

Tags: ember.js

How can I manually create links at runtime and have them not cause a page reload?

For example at runtime I want to be able to do

```
<a href='/mylink'>My Link</a>
```

and click that link and cause it to route properly, without a page reload. I am aware that this is terrible practice, but I have a very specific use case.

Possible useful link: 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10979

Comment: is the route defined before (at app-start)?

Comment: The route is defined but it's not linked to, if that makes sense. If I click that link - it loads the proper page. I just want it to load it without RELOADING the page

Comment: then why don't you do a normal `{{#link-to 'mylink'}}`?

Comment: It's a rather contrived situation - but I need to add routes to my page using my chrome extension. So I pretty much have to be able to do it from the javascript console

Comment: Sounds like you'd need that link to trigger an event/action that in turn calls the Ember router service.